# How to swap the result of a predicate to the opposite? True to False, and vise versa

Tags: prolog

I need to make a function that returns True, if a list has no duplicates, and False if it does.
Use of appendTo is mandatory. I've managed to make a function, but it is basically the opposite result:
**True** if it has duplicates,
**False** if it doesn't
Now I need to swap the results somehow...

I've tried using not(), but it didn't work as I expected.
Maybe someone can help me? :)

```
appendTo([ ], L, L).
appendTo([X|L1], L2, [X|L]):- appendTo(L1, L2, L).

no_duplicates(List) :- 
    appendTo(Start, [Current | End], List),
    (appendTo(_, [Current | _], Start) ; appendTo(_, [Current | _], End)).
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell the recursion when to stop (first line):

```
appendTo([],L2,L2).
appendTo([X|L1], L2, [X|L]):- appendTo(L1, L2, L).

duplicates(List) :- 
    appendTo(Start, [Current | End], List),
    (   appendTo(_, [Current | _], Start) 
    ;   appendTo(_, [Current | _], End)
    ).

no_duplicates(List) :-
    \+ duplicates(List).
```

Test cases:

```
?- no_duplicates([a,b,c,b]).
false.

?- no_duplicates([a,b,c]).
true.
```

Tested with [Swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). Also `\+/1` is the predicate you should use instead of `not/1`; it means as much as "cannot be proven".

Using only one predicate is a bit more tricky because of the negation. This one should work:

```
no_duplicates(List) :- 
    appendTo(Start, [Current | End], List),
    (   appendTo(_, [Current | _], Start)
    ;   appendTo(_, [Current | _], End) 
    ),
    !, 
    fail.
no_duplicates(_).
```

Test cases

```
?- no_duplicates([a,b,c,b]).
false.

?-no_duplicates([a,b,c]).
true.
```

The cut (`!`) prevents further backtracking.

Comment: Is it possible to do it all in one functions? Without the assisting predicate

Comment: Thank you, i fixed my formatting, now it shows tail of recursion